# ASP.Net MVC2 web app capable of plugins and themes architecture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering if ASP.Net MVC 2 is a good choice for my current project. I want to build a social site that will allow for plugins or modular apps to be added on to it. An example of what I am talking about would be socialengine.net or even Joomla.

I was thinking that mvc areas would make good modular apps to plug into a core app but wondering if some sort of installer could be created that would wire things up automatically.

Anyone know of any examples of this somewhere on the net?

Answer (score 1):

you can also have a look at [MVCMS](http://cmsmvc.codeplex.com/) http://cmsmvc.codeplex.com/ as a starting point, theme's and plugins are already built in, it's still in early stages, but it does the basics

Answer (score 1):

Those links are all pretty old.  Have a look at Poartable Areas in MvcContrib, and the detailed instructions: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib.aspx

Comment: I read through the portable areas, but it seems those are built as class libraries where as having a an area in a WAP would be more ideal providing more IDE bells and whistles.